# I have a SSIS package with .CSV file where data is like this

Tags: sql, ssis

I have csv file with data like this, How can I handle to successfully push all data in sql table using SSIS. The first row data always have problem.

[image]

Comment: HI John, hae you tried using the ssis component fat file source and an oleDB destination? If so what error are you getting?

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/

Comment: Please use this for you question's solution.https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6149/import-text-and-csv-files-into-sql-server-database-with-ssis-script-task/